# React-query useQuery, GraphQL + fetch. How to pass variables?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch-api, react-query

I'm trying to fetch data from my **Strapi GraphQl api** and paginate them. For that I need to pass down variables. I'm using **react-query** and **fetch api**.

Here I declare my variables and query.

```
const endpoint = "http://localhost:1337/graphql"
let limit: number = 10;
let start: number = 0;
export const QUERY = `
query fetchProducts ($limit: Int!, $start: Int!)  {
  products(limit: $limit, start: $start) {
    title
    price
    slug
    image {
      formats
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Here is my fetching function

```
  async function fetchData(endpoint: string, query: string, limit: number, start: number) {
    const res = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: query }),
    });
    const json = await res.json();
    const {
        data: { products },
    } = json;
    start += 10; //when refetching, it fetches another 10
    return products;
}
```

And here is useQuery hook from react-query

```
const { data, status, refetch } = useQuery(["blog", limit, start], () => fetchData(endpoint, QUERY, limit, start), {
    keepPreviousData: true,
});
```

I get errors:

"Variable "$limit" of required type "Int!" was not provided

"Variable "$start" of required type "Int!" was not provided.

**So I'm not passing variables correctly. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a react-query specific perspective, it looks good:

- having all variables as part of the query key
- passing them correctly to the queryFn

I'm no graphQL expert, but looking at [this example blog post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/21/send-graphql-queries-with-the-fetch-api-without-using-apollo-urql-or-other-graphql-clients/) on how to use graphql with `fetch`, you need to pass `variables` next to the `query` as the `body` of your `fetch` request.

Something like:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
  query: query,
  variables: { limit, start }
}),
```

I think this becomes a bit easier if you use a lightweigt abstraction, like `graphql-request`, which is also what the [react-query example](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/basic-graphql-request) uses.

Comment: Thank you, adding variables to body fixed the problem! :)